# Свайп на следующую статью

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно сделать так, чтобы с телефона можно было свайпнуть на следующую статью, у wordpress, есть стационарная переключалка `<?php previous_post_link('<a>%link</a>')?>`, не нужно аякс, нужно просто чтобы при свайпе срабатывала функция, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android) содержится ответ на ваш вопрос чистым JS с нативными функциями, чтобы вы случайно не изобрели велосипед :)

```
// Вешаем на прикосновение функцию handleTouchStart
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);  
// А на движение пальцем по экрану - handleTouchMove      
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;                                                        

function handleTouchStart(evt) {                                         
    xDown = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                      
    yDown = evt.touches[0].clientY;                                      
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(evt) {
    if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
        return;
    }

    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
    // немного поясню здесь. Тут берутся модули движения по оси абсцисс и ординат (почему модули? потому что если движение сделано влево или вниз, то его показатель будет отрицательным) и сравнивается, чего было больше: движения по абсциссам или ординатам. Нужно это для того, чтобы, если пользователь провел вправо, но немного наискосок вниз, сработал именно коллбэк для движения вправо, а ни как-то иначе.
    if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            /* left swipe */ 
        } else {
            /* right swipe */
        }                       
    } else { // Это вам, в общем-то, не надо, вы ведь только влево-вправо собираетесь двигать
        if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
            /* up swipe */ 
        } else { 
            /* down swipe */
        }                                                                 
    }
    /* reset values */
    xDown = null;
    yDown = null;                                             
};
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: @VenZell сразу хотел так поступить, но потерял ссылку на эту страницу. Теперь поправил ответ.