# Как с помощью свайпа добавлять/удалять классы?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как на сенсорных экранах с помощью свайпа добавлять/удалять классы, например если двигаешь пальцем слева-на-право - добавить класc.Справа-на-лево - удалить.

Comment: Скорее придется юзать js библиотеки, чтобы отлавливать свайп, а потом в коллбэке делать все, что захочешь

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528938/Свайп-на-следующую-статью

Comment: @Air Давать ссылку на тостер - это топчик :D

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Согласен....

Comment: @Air на Ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмем за основу вот этот [код](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android?answertab=votes#tab-top) , и добавим логику изменения классов

```js
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;

function getTouches(evt) {
  return evt.touches ||             // browser API
         evt.originalEvent.touches; // jQuery
}                                                     

function handleTouchStart(evt) {
    const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
    xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
    yDown = firstTouch.clientY;     
    
    //Убираем классы
    test.classList.remove('left');
    test.classList.remove('right');
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(evt) {
    if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
        return;
    }

    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;

    if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            /* left swipe */ 
            //Добавляем класс
            test.classList.add('left');
        } else {
            /* right swipe */
            //Добавляем класс
            test.classList.add('right');
        }                       
    } else {
        if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
            /* up swipe */
        } else { 
            /* down swipe */
        }                                                                 
    }
    /* reset values */
    xDown = null;
    yDown = null;                                             
};

var test = document.querySelector('.js-test');
```

```css
.js-test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.js-test.left {
  background-color: green;
}

.js-test.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-test"></div>
```

Comment: Уже давно решил.

Comment: Это хорошо, что решили, но вопрос то закрыть надо

Comment: Хитрый вы. Теряется актуальность таких вопросов. Ведь я могу тоже ответить на собственный вопрос. При том, этим кодом я уже реализовал свои потребности. Я хочу сказать он не ваш. Ну, хорошо, держите. Будем считать, что ответили вы.

Comment: и этот код неполный. Мой дополненный. Например можно указать размер свайпа, для засчитывания.